# Show data in tooltip via php?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, tooltip

I was wondering how I'd go about displaying data from a phpmyadmin database in a tooltip on my website?

If the logged in user hovers over a certain field, more information will be displayed in the tooltip.

I have no idea on how even go about this, so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: just use <input id="some_id" type="hidden" value="your_data"> and then retrieve that information via javascript on hover

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can the value="your_data" be a piece of PHP code?

Comment: FInd a tooltip example and echo the said row in there; this isn't so hard you know. You just need to put your mind to it.

Comment: I could easily write this out, but then you'd of not have learned anything; given if you're serious about coding. Try something out and when you experienced difficulty, update your post to contain what it was, then we'd be glad to take a look at it.

Comment: Cool will do so thanks.

Comment: @MailBlade yeah of course you can scape the php variable that you need with <?= your_php_var ?> (outside of the main php context)

Answer (score 2):

first of all you need jquery ui. you can use the code below for that

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

second you need a database.
lets say your database is myproducts->id,productname,productdate

and lets say the tag is

```
<h1  data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top">product1</h1>
```

then you need the code bellow to tooltip and get the text from the tag and send it to a php file(lets say the name is c.php) via ajax

```
<script>
 $(function() {

     $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
         open: function( event, ui ) {
            var x = $(this);
            var text = $(this).html();
            $.ajax({
                type:'post',
                url:'c.php',
                data:{
                    'text':text
                },
                success:function(html){

                    x.tooltip({
                        content:html
                    });

                }

            });

         }
         });
});
 </script>
```

then your c.php file must containt the code as below:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("host","username","password","databasename");
if(isset($_POST['text']))
{
    $text = $_POST['text'];
    $query = mysqli_query($con, "select * from myproducts where productname='$text'");
    $result = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
    if(!empty($result))
    {
        echo json_encode($result);
    }
}//if
?>
```

you see what i did was that if i tooltip over a text the code will send the text of the tag by ajax to another php file and that file will get the text(which can be anything realy like names) and  sends back json that it got from database and database checked the text that we sent to it and got all the information about it. at the end json get called back to ajax and by x variable which is our main object that we tooltip on we tooltip again and show the information that we got from database via json.

at the end if you hover over product1 all the information about product1 will show as tooltip

Comment: im wondering why this question got rated down since it is a complex and good question

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. Sorry for only responding now.

Comment: Yes it is a very broad question, and I am even using a component "VirtueMart", which adds another layer of difficulty. I have already customised the component to my liking in a lot of areas using php and javascript. However, this was a bit confusing since there are a lot of products.

I will definitely be trying your solution out! Thanks again I really appreciate it.

Comment: you're welcome. by the way don't forget to keep title="Tooltip on top" (or any title realy) for your tag otherwise it wont work.